# Need to replace Currency Shortforms

Tags: plugins, php, functions, pluggable, function-exists

I want to replace the currency shorten alphabet, it is currently in M, L and So on.
I want to change to indian currency number format like K, L and CR

below is code:

```php
if(!function_exists('houzez_number_shorten')) {

    function houzez_number_shorten($number, $precision = 0, $divisors = null) {
    $number = houzez_clean_price_20($number);

        if (!isset($divisors)) {
            $divisors = array(
                pow(1000, 0) => '', // 1000^0 == 1
                pow(1000, 1) => 'K', // Thousand
                pow(1000, 2) => 'M', // Million
                pow(1000, 3) => 'B', // Billion
                pow(1000, 4) => 'T', // Trillion
                pow(1000, 5) => 'Qa', // Quadrillion
                pow(1000, 6) => 'Qi', // Quintillion
            );    
        }
        
        foreach ($divisors as $divisor => $shorthand) {
            if (abs($number) < ($divisor * 1000)) {
                // Match found
                break;
            }
        }
        //Match found or not found use the last defined value for divisor
        $price = number_format($number / $divisor, 1);
        $price = str_replace(".0","",$price);
        return $price . $shorthand;
    }
}
```

I am not good at coding, so any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divisors loop assumes that the next row is 1000 times larger than the current one so I think you'll have to change the logic here, e.g. keep iterating until the divisor is too big and use the previous one e.g.

```php
if (!isset($divisors)) {
    $divisors = array(
        pow(10, 0) => '',
        pow(10, 3) => 'K', // Thousand
        pow(10, 5) => 'L', // Lakh
        pow(10, 7) => 'CR', // Crore
    );
}

$divisor = 1;
$shorthand = '';
foreach ($divisors as $next_divisor => $next_shorthand) {
    if (abs($number) < $next_divisor) {
        // Too big; use previous row
        break;
    }
    $divisor = $next_divisor;
    $shorthand = $next_shorthand;
}
```

I'd guess that's all you need to change. (I don't know if you need to tell number_format to  not use thousands too but hopefully it'll take that from the locale, and you wouldn't be showing thousands unless you've got 1000+ crore anyway.) Note also that the existing function does not use the $precision parameter.

Comment: Thank you, this really solve the issue. Big thanks to you Rup